# Listening to React-Native Safari Redirect back to App

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth, callback, deep-linking

I have a React Native app, that opens a portal to Oauth sign-in in safari:

```
const handleLogin = () => {
    Linking.canOpenURL('myappname://myapproute').then((supported) => {
      if (supported) {
        console.log('can open url');
        Linking.openURL(myurl);
      } else {
        console.log("Don't know how to open URI: " + 'myappname:myapproute');
      }
    });
  };
```

Inside `myurl`, I also supply a redirect URI, `myappname://myapproute`.

After authorizing in the Oauth, there is a button to be taken back to my app. The normal iOS popup 'Open this page in "myappname"?' shows, and when clicked, redirects back to my app.

I need to listen to the callback that opened my app, and extract relevant parameters that may have been supplied. To do this, I registered an event listener:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleOpenURL = (event) => {
      console.log(`event is: ${event}`);
    };
    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);

       return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);
    };
  }, []);
```

However, my handler never runs, despite my app being opened. What could I possibly be doing wrong? I made sure my listener was registered. One time only I was able to view the extracted parameters, but it was while fiddling around with the app and I could not replicate it.

Comment: Is the App in the foreground when the user enter the credentials or do you open safari and put your app in the background. In the latter case you can try using ```Linking.getInitialURL()``` instead of ```Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);```

Comment: The app is running as a background process. We are tabbed into safari, but my app is not force closed. I was under the impression `getInitialURL` is only if your app is force closed?

Comment: In the docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#1-if-the-app-is-already-open-the-app-is-foregrounded-and-a-linking-url-event-is-fired)
```Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);``` is only for open app in foreground

Comment: By the background, you mean the app is not force closed, but not focused either, right? If so, that is the situation I am in, but the event listener is not working for me.

Comment: In case you are using react-navigation you could use a different approach by defining NavigationContainer linking property  -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/

Comment: Thanks that worked feel free to leave an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using react-navigation you could use a different approach by defining NavigationContainer [linking property](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links)

```
const config = {
  screens: {
      screens: {
        Login: 'users/:token',
    },
  },
};
```